# TS2740 is missing the following properties from type, Typescript, NestJS

Tags: javascript, mongodb, types, graphql, nestjs

I have an interface, for detail input value:

```
input DocumentDetailInput {
  vat: Float!
  isSaleWithPrescription: Boolean!
  valueCountRound: Float!
  paymentType: String!
  exportNoBill: Boolean!
}
```

Then, i want add only 2 value:

```
      detail: {
        vat: input.vat,
        exportNoBill: input.exportNobill
      },
```

error:

```
is missing the following properties from type 'DocumentDetail': valueCountRound, isSaleWithPrescription, paymentType.ts(2740)
```

Comment: You can't just exclude things from an interface, that's the entire point of interfaces.

Comment: What's the question here? You have a defined interface with no optional properties, created a an object of that interface type without all the fields and typescript got mad at you for it and threw an error. This is exactly what's supposed to happen

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all !!
I have solution

```
const detailInput = {
      vat: input.vat,
      exportNoBill: input.exportNobill
    } as DocumentDetailInput
```

and

```
detail: DocumentDetailInput
```

Now I can't just exclude things from DocumentDetailInput interface !!